# in_app_purchase how do I get the data needed for android verification from the serverVerificationData

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, android-billing

I am trying to implement server side verification for IAP's in my flutter app. I am using the package

https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

version: ^0.3.4+8

And I am confused how I get the data to verify my purchase for android and IOS. In the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase/latest/in_app_purchase/PurchaseVerificationData-class.html) they say

> "or verify the data using your own server with
> serverVerificationData."

This string seems to return some kind of encoded string. How do I then extract the needed data from this string? I tried base64Decode() since the localVerificationData is base64Encoded but this did not work.

Android needs a package name, purchase id and purchaseToken. And Ios needs a object receipt-data. I am confused on how I am to get that data from the serverVerificationData string.

I am currently implementing android first.

The the localVerificationData documentation says

> The data used for local verification.
>
> If the source is IAPSource.AppStore, this data is a based64 encoded
> string. The structure of the payload is defined using ASN.1. If the
> source is IAPSource.GooglePlay, this data is a JSON String.

So the serverVerificationData must be different from the localVerificationData then since it doesn't look like JSON at all. I am also not sure if it is safe to post the serverVerificationData here since it may contain sensitive information.

This is a string similar to the one I got on android only I changed all the letters, numbers etc. So it's just about the format

```
zdfdzcdshxvbxmgbafdxvdzt.JK-GR58OHRPOGFEFHEGVEACBEIFDAPDH_EFHEWFEHFHPEGVERBWBASZWDAWODPAWD-HDSWCGOEWFP-EFPEQFHPEDHEWYIFEWFUWEFDASCNAQWFDefphFEQUIWEFpofgewpfFEWHFPWEF
```

In the repo they show that they call the _verifyPurchase(purchase); which has no implementation in the example.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/in_app_purchase#listening-to-purchase-updates

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/5a183ac54a515be096d01f3a35546c5d89a30dca/packages/in_app_purchase/example/lib/main.dart#L350

And they say you should always verify

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/5a183ac54a515be096d01f3a35546c5d89a30dca/packages/in_app_purchase/example/lib/main.dart#L328

This is my current code

```
 Future<dynamic> verifyAndroid(PurchaseDetails details) async {
    DatabaseService databaseService = Get.find<DatabaseService>();
    String verificationData = details.verificationData.serverVerificationData;
    // zdfdzcdshxvbxmgbafdxvdzt.JK-GR58OHRPOGFEFHEGVEACBEIFDAPDH_EFHEWFEHFHPEGVERBWBASZWDAWODPAWD-HDSWCGOEWFP-EFPEQFHPEDHEWYIFEWFUWEFDASCNAQWFDefphFEQUIWEFpofgewpfFEWHFPWEF
    String packageName = ''; //get from verificationData 
    String productId = ''; //get from verificationData 
    String purchaseToken = ''; //get from verificationData 
    final response = await databaseService.verifyInAppPurchaseAndroid(packageName, productId, purchaseToken);
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Try RevenueCat they can handle the verification on the server-side for you

Comment: I've seen it, but I'm not interested in using it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the data was in the detail.verificationData.localVerificationData instead of the detail.verificationData.serverVerificationData and detail.verificationData.serverVerificationData is the purchase token on Android.